# XSLT for loop or alternative for node duplication

Tags: xml, for-loop, iteration, xslt-1.0

In my reading, it's become quite obvious that the only sane workaround to `for i .. m` loops in XSLT 1.0 is using a recursive template.

Unless someone can explain otherwise, it further seems that given the constraints of XSLT processing, this approach isn't generically reusable.

Anyway, given an input snippet (*the context node in this case*) of:

```
<items count="3">
    <item>
        <name>Name</name>
        <description>Description</description>
    </item>
</items>
```

Is there a reusable strategy to duplicate the `<item>` child based on the `count` attribute? The expected output here would simply be

```
<item>
    <name>Name</name>
    <description>Description</description>
</item>
<item>
    <name>Name</name>
    <description>Description</description>
</item>
<item>
    <name>Name</name>
    <description>Description</description>
</item>
```

I intend to perform further transformations on the `<item>` nodes, however I don't think they're relevant.

Reusability is a point of concern for me, for the simple reason that the `count` attribute is quite common among elements of the input documents, and the semantic intent is just as described by my example above.

If I were to use the recursive-iterator approach, I'd have to bake that into every template (*which would be very not DRY; more like very WET, as in "why even try"; but I digress*)

If there *is* a strategy to creating a generic `for` template, with which any transformation operations can be performed, that would be just spectacular. If I can get away without using any recursive-iterators, if some gem of a function for this purpose is tucked away in XSLT 1.0, that would be equally spectacular.

Anyway, how can I accomplish this? Do I need to resort to the WET approach, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with recursion. It should be pretty easy to make it generic enough for this situation.

Here's an example. In addition to outputting the child element the same number as `count`, I also change the `name` element to `new_elem` (just to show additional transformation)...

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@count]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="dupe">
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="@count"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="dupe">
        <xsl:param name="count"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="$count > 1">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="dupe" select=".">
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <new_elem><xsl:value-of select="."/></new_elem>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output** (using the input from the question)

```
<item>
   <new_elem>Name</new_elem>
   <description>Description</description>
</item>
<item>
   <new_elem>Name</new_elem>
   <description>Description</description>
</item>
<item>
   <new_elem>Name</new_elem>
   <description>Description</description>
</item>
```

If you could use XSLT 2.0, you could iterate like you stated at the beginning of your question:

**XSLT 2.0** (Produces the same output as above. It would be slightly different if there are more than one child elements of `*[@count]`)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@count]">
        <xsl:variable name="curr" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to @count">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$curr/*"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <new_elem><xsl:value-of select="."/></new_elem>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You can eliminate the `xsl:if` by changing the `select` on the line right after it to `current()[$count > 1]`. There's also one possible drawback in your current approach in that this will duplicate the individual elements of a containing node instead of the whole contents. For example `<a count='2'><b /><c /></a>` would result in `<b /><b /><c /><c />` instead of `<b /><c /><b /><c />`. You could change this by modifying the first line of the second template to `select="."`, and removing the `select` from the second line of the third template.

Comment: Nice For loop coding with both the versions, +1.

Answer (score 2):

> If there is a strategy to creating a generic for template, with which
>   any transformation operations can be performed, that would be just
>   spectacular. If I can get away without using any recursive-iterators,
>   if some gem of a function for this purpose is tucked away in XSLT 1.0,
>   that would be equally spectacular.
>
> Anyway, how can I accomplish this? Do I need to resort to the WET
>   approach, or is there a better way?

**The wanted DRY-ness is a trivial application of the [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)'s template/function [`iter`](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/iter.xsl?revision=1.3&view=markup):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/" xmlns:myRepeat="f:myRepeat"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xsl f myRepeat">
 <xsl:import href="iter.xsl"/>

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <myRepeat:myRepeat/>
  <xsl:variable name="vFunRepeat" select="document('')/*/myRepeat:*[1]"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vAdditive" select="/*/*[1]"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:call-template name="iter">
          <xsl:with-param name="pTimes" select="@count"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pFun" select="$vFunRepeat"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pX" select="/.."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="myRepeat:*" mode="f:FXSL">
    <xsl:param name="arg1"/>

    <xsl:copy-of select="$arg1 | $vAdditive"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<items count="3">
    <item>
        <name>Name</name>
        <description>Description</description>
    </item>
</items>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<item>
   <name>Name</name>
   <description>Description</description>
</item>
<item>
   <name>Name</name>
   <description>Description</description>
</item>
<item>
   <name>Name</name>
   <description>Description</description>
</item>
```

**Do note**:

1. You don't have to write any recursive template at all.
2. The `iter` template, like most other FXSL's templates is very general and powerful, eliminating the need for the programmer to write and debug recursion time after time.
3. FXSL provides the wanted DRY-ness and stimulates thinking in more abstract -- thus more powerful constructs -- functions, folds, iterations, ..., etc.
4. It happens so that this problem has a trivial solution in XSLT 2.0 (`<xsl:for-each select="1 to @count">`), but there are many other problems, whose solution in XSLT 2.0 isn't so straight-forward. FXSL helps solve any such "difficult" problems by using its generic and powerful implementations of the most general and powerful higher-order functions -- folds, maps, scans, zips, ..., etc.

---

II. **Using the [Piez method](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9945e300)** (when there is a known upper limit for the value of `@count`)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vStyle" select="document('')"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vNodes" select=
   "$vStyle//node()|$vStyle//@* | $vStyle//namespace::*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vAdditive" select="/*/*[1]"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:for-each select="$vNodes[not(position() > current()/@count)]">
       <xsl:copy-of select="$vAdditive"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<item>
   <name>Name</name>
   <description>Description</description>
</item>
<item>
   <name>Name</name>
   <description>Description</description>
</item>
<item>
   <name>Name</name>
   <description>Description</description>
</item>
```

**Do note**:

When the Piez method can be used, recursion is avoided completely.

**Disclaimer**:

I was happy to develop FXSL 11-12 years ago, and I have mentioned it thousands of times since then, including two conference papers, without knowing that I should provide a disclaimer :)